# put objects of mapState in an array (vue2/js/vuex)

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to put in an array('allData') 2 array of objects from 'roomContent' and 'roomSurveys. And when i check with vue inspector my allData is well created but not filled with the elements I want...

My goal is to display the components (post-card and answer-card which are components) thanks to a array(allData) that I can handle but for that I have to insert in this array the post and survey's data with mapState.

here is my script:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import AnswerCard from '~/components/Answers/AnswerCard'
import PostCard from '~/components/Content/PostCard'
// // import DecodedTagInHour from '~/components/Graphics/DecodedTagInHour'
// import DecodedTagMap from '~/components/Map/DecodedTagMap'

export default {
  name: 'ContentDisplay',
  components: {
    AnswerCard,
    PostCard,
    // DecodedTagInHour,
    // DecodedTagMap
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('surveys', ['roomSurveys']),
    ...mapState('post', ['roomContent']),
    
  },
  mounted() {
    this.allData.push(...this.roomSurveys, ...this.roomContent)
  },
  data() {
    return {
      allData: [],
    }
  },
```

here is my template :

```
 <div v-for="data in allData" :key="data.id">
        <post-card v-if="data.type === 'post'"
          >
        </post-card>
        <answer-card  v-if="data.type === 'survey'">
        </answer-card>
      </div>
```

and like u can see my array contains nothing :
[vue inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8z6S.png)

Comment: i dont need of mapGetters because like u can see I already get my elements with mapState

Comment: You can [edit] the question to add more info in it, instead of comments

Comment: What's inside `<post-card>` shouldn't you be passing some  data as props to it?

Comment: i update my post thx for the tips and i answered to ur question in my post @TJ

Comment: If your project is in GitHub, importing it (or a simplified version) into CodeSandbox would help for analysis.

Comment: Are you sure, that these variables hold something at the time the SFC is `mounted()`? How do you update the state?

Comment: Something fishy is going on here; via your screenshot, your Vuex state bindings are working, and I verified that the syntax on `this.allData.push()` is good too. No console warnings, just... nothing. There's gotta be something else going on here. Can you check what's going on in mounted by logging? Eg. add `console.log(this.allData, this.roomSurveys, this.roomContent)` to your `mounted()` before/ after the push.